# rotating integration in R

Tags: r, rotation, integration, volume

I have tried to find an answer to my question using the search function, but couldnt find one which fits my Problem.

I would like to know wheather there is a package in R which I can use to calculate the volume of an object, depicted as an function which is rotating arround the X-axis. I think this procedure is called something like "rotating Integration".

Would be awsome if someone could tell me wheather there is a way to do this in R.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I think you need [Disc integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration). Express function in required form and use [integrate](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/integrate.html).

Comment: That is actually what I am looking for, thanks! Alltough I dont understand how the "integrate"-function can produce me the volume of the rotating "object". If I express my function and then use it with "integrate" it will just calculate the area under the function but not the volume. I can't use the area to transform it to an volume then. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Let's choose a simple figure - cone of rotation `y=x` around `x`. Volume of cone with `h=1` and `r=1` is `1/3*pi*h*r^2 = 1.047198`.

Surface line is:

```
y <- function(x) x
```

Apply [disc integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration) formula:

```
pi*integrate(function(x) y(x)^2, 0, 1)$value
```

Result is also `1.047198`.

Comment: Thanks you very much, now I got it...had a stupid mistake in my function so it didn't work in the beginning.